# Create a 'partial' window function to update data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table where I want to use window functions to fill in some NULLs, but I only want data to flow downwards, based on a Rank column in the table. Using window functions (`PARTITION BY`), all rows get assigned the same data, which is not the requirement here.

The initial table has NULL values for columns A and B where Rank=2 and ID=1, which I want to populate with the values where Rank=1. Column C is NULL where Rank=1, and 15 where Rank=2 and ID=1, which needs to stay the same way.

Here is the structure of the initial table, the desired output, as well as some sample code. I am unsure how to incorporate the rank into the partition by statement
Initial Table

```
ID    A       B      C      Rank
---------------------------------
1     10      10     NULL   1
1     NULL    NULL   15     2
2     10      NULL   NULL   1
2     NULL    NULL   15     2
2     NULL    NULL   15     3
```

Target table

```
ID    A       B      C      Rank
---------------------------------
1     10      10     NULL   1
1     10      10     15     2
2     10      NULL   NULL   1
2     10      NULL   15     2
2     10      NULL   15     3
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(A) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
    MAX(B) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
    MAX(C) OVER (PARTITION BY ID),
    Rank
FROM 
    TBL;
```

As expected, partitioning by both, ID and Rank leads to no changes in the initial table

Comment: Appearing to have promising results by including an 'ORDER BY' statement in the brackets for the Partition by... (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Rank), will update post if this is the correct solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select
    id,
    coalesce(a, first_value(a) over (partition by id order by rnk)) a,
    coalesce(b, first_value(b) over (partition by id order by rnk)) b,
    coalesce(c, first_value(c) over (partition by id order by rnk)) c,
    rnk
from tbl;
```

Note that `rank` is a language keyword (as in window function `rank() over()`), hence not a good choice for a column name. I renamed it to `rnk` in the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7645e73ba8c247a00bde8dc068dde654)**:

```
id |  a |    b |    c | rnk
-: | -: | ---: | ---: | --:
 1 | 10 |   10 | null |   1
 1 | 10 |   10 |   15 |   2
 2 | 10 | null | null |   1
 2 | 10 | null |   15 |   2
 2 | 10 | null |   15 |   3
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I wasn't using Rank in the actual data. Interestingly, I'm getting the same result using coalesce/first_value, vs just doing a max(). It seems to be as my data will only have one potential (non null) value for a given column

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5161c89cb8464b45381d0f3770fd6ea2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `ignore nulls` in any window function.  That is the best approach.  In your example, you only have a value or `NULL`.  If this is the case, you can use a cumulative max:

```
select id,
       coalesce(a, max(a) over (partition by id order by rank)) as a,
       coalesce(b, max(b) over (partition by id order by rank)) as b,
       coalesce(c, max(c) over (partition by id order by rank)) as c,
       rank
from tbl;
```

If this is not the case, the logic is trickier.  But actually, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question if that is the case.  Let this one be about the data as you have presented it.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't entirely correct, since this doesn't consider the separate IDs. The solution presented by GMB is working

Comment: @hamela777 . . . I see that.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there by the partitioning. You need to use a relatively infrequently used approach that limits the partition size - in this case, all the preceding rows only (so as to not use any 'future' when calculating the row's values).

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID int, Rnk int, A int, B int, C int)
INSERT INTO #Temp (ID, Rnk, A, B, C)
    VALUES  (1, 1, 10,   10,   NULL),  
            (1, 2, NULL, NULL, 15),      
            (2, 1, 10,   NULL, NULL),    
            (2, 2, NULL, NULL, 15),      
            (2, 3, NULL, NULL, 15)  

SELECT      ID, Rnk, 
            MAX(A) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rnk ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS A_Fill,
            MAX(B) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rnk ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS B_Fill,
            MAX(C) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Rnk ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS C_Fill
    FROM    #Temp
```

I believe this outputs the same results as above e.g.,

```
ID | Rnk | A_Fill | B_Fill | C_Fill
1  | 1   | 10     | 10     | NULL
1  | 2   | 10     | 10     | 15
2  | 1   | 10     | NULL   | NULL
2  | 2   | 10     | NULL   | 15
2  | 3   | 10     | NULL   | 15
```

Note that if you add two more rows for ID = 2 (with rnks 4 and 5) and the rest NULL, this approach puts 15 into the 'C' Columns, which the above (COALESCE/FIRST_VALUE) doesn't, I believe.

```
ID | Rnk | A_Fill | B_Fill | C_Fill
1  | 1   | 10     | 10     | NULL
1  | 2   | 10     | 10     | 15
2  | 1   | 10     | NULL   | NULL
2  | 2   | 10     | NULL   | 15
2  | 3   | 10     | NULL   | 15
2  | 4   | 10     | NULL   | 15
2  | 5   | 10     | NULL   | 15
```

Here is a [DB_Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2aebf78f891bc1266698e1fa12cb8a36) showing differences (based on previous ones above)